# NDK build opencv error

Tags: opencv, build, android-ndk

I encountered an error using the NDK way to compile the source code, I will opencv source code copied to the jni directory, prepared Android.mk and Application.mk as well as the source file. Mk file, compiled the following error, please also Give some advice, thanks! ! !

Operating System: Ubuntu 17210 64bit
opencv version: 3.3
android-ndk version: 14b

```
log:
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_io_base64.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_addWeighted.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_convertTo.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_math.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_split.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_inRange.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_umat.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_stat.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_dft.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_abs.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_bitwise.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_cvround.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_compare.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_merge.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_mat.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_sort.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_main.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_norm.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_lut.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_reduce.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_dot.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_gpumat.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_arithm.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_minmaxloc.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_usage_flags.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_bufferpool.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_matop.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_gemm.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_arithm.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_dxt.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= perf_channels.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: opencv <= cuda_host_mem.cpp
In file included from /home/jiangc/opencv3.3Ndk库/hello-jni/jni/core/src/cuda_host_mem.cpp:44:
In file included from /home/jiangc/opencv3.3Ndk库/hello-jni/jni/core/src/precomp.hpp:49:
In file included from /home/jiangc/opencv3.3Ndk库/hello-jni/jni/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:56:
In file included from /home/jiangc/opencv3.3Ndk库/hello-jni/jni/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52:
In file included from /home/jiangc/opencv3.3Ndk库/hello-jni/jni/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:189:
In file included from /home/jiangc/opencv3.3Ndk库/hello-jni/jni/include/opencv2/core/cv_cpu_dispatch.h:32:
In file included from /home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/emmintrin.h:27:
In file included from /home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/xmmintrin.h:27:
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:47:5: note: 
      '__builtin_isless' declared here
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:47:25: error: 
      too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
                        ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:64:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:81:12: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:143:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:173:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:203:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:230:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:253:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:274:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:301:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:324:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:345:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:366:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'; did you mean '__builtin_arm_qadd'?
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:366:19: note: 
      '__builtin_arm_qadd' declared here
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:366:40: error: 
      cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int' with an rvalue of type '__v8qi'
      (vector of 8 'char' values)
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:387:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'; did you mean '__builtin_arm_qadd'?
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:366:19: note: 
      '__builtin_arm_qadd' declared here
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:387:40: error: 
      cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int' with an rvalue of type '__v4hi'
      (vector of 4 'short' values)
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:408:19: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'; did you mean '__builtin_arm_qadd'?
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:366:19: note: 
      '__builtin_arm_qadd' declared here
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib64/clang/3.8.275480/include/mmintrin.h:408:40: error: 
      cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int' with an rvalue of type '__v2si'
      (vector of 2 'int' values)
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [/home/jiangc/opencv3.3Ndk库/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/opencv/core/src/cuda_host_mem.o] Error 1


Android.mk file
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCAL_PATH :=$(call my-dir)
ZLIB_PATH:=/home/jiangc/android-ndk-r14b/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr
include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_MODULE := opencv

#源文件 mk 文件
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/core_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/dnn_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/features2d_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/highgui_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/imgcodecs_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/imgproc_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/ml_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/objdetect_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/photo_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/stitching_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/videoio_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/video_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/viz_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/calib3d_source.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/ts_source.mk

#include $(LOCAL_PATH)/cuda_source.mk

#包含源文件变量
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CORE_SOURCE) \
                   $(DNN_SOURCE)     \
                   $(FEATURES2D_SOURCE)   \
                   $(HIGHGUI_SOURCE)    \
                   $(IMGCODECS_SOURCE)    \
                   $(IMAGEPROC_SOURCE)    \
                   $(ML_SOURCE)    \
                   $(OBJDETECT_SOURCE)    \
                   $(PHOTO_SOURCE)    \
                   $(STITCHING_SOURCE)   \
                   $(VIDEOIO_SOURCE)    \
                   $(VIDEO_SOURCE)    \
                   $(VIZ_SOURCE)       \
                   $(TS_SOURCE)\
                   $(CALIB3D_SOURCE)

                   #$(CUDAWARPING_SOURCE)  \
                   #$(CUDASTEREO_SOURCE)   \
                   #$(CUDAIMGPROC_SOURCE)    \
                   #$(CUDAOBJDETECT_SOURCE)   \
                   #$(CUDAFEATURES2D_SOURCE)   \
                   #$(CUDALEGACY_SOURCE)   \
                   #$(CUDALEGACY_SOURCE)    \
                   #$(CUDAARITHM_SOURCE)    \
                   #$(CUDAOPTFLOW_SOURCE)    \
                   #$(CUDACODEC_SOURCE)      \
#定义include文件位置
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/  \
                  $(ZLIB_PATH)/include

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz 

LOCAL_LDLIBS+= -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

### Application.mk file

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions  
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a



One of the mk source files
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CORE_SOURCE = core/perf/perf_io_base64.cpp\
core/perf/perf_addWeighted.cpp\
core/perf/perf_convertTo.cpp\
core/perf/perf_math.cpp\
core/perf/perf_split.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_inRange.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_umat.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_stat.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_dft.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_abs.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_bitwise.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_cvround.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_compare.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_merge.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_mat.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_sort.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_main.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_norm.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_lut.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_reduce.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_dot.cpp    \
core/perf/cuda/perf_gpumat.cpp   \
core/perf/perf_arithm.cpp    \
core/perf/perf_minmaxloc.cpp    \
core/perf/opencl/perf_usage_flags.cpp    \
core/perf/opencl/perf_bufferpool.cpp    \
core/perf/opencl/perf_matop.cpp    \
core/perf/opencl/perf_gemm.cpp     \
core/perf/opencl/perf_arithm.cpp   \
core/perf/opencl/perf_dxt.cpp    \
core/perf/opencl/perf_channels.cpp   \
core/src/cuda_host_mem.cpp   \
core/src/rand.cpp   \
core/src/lapack.cpp   \
core/src/parallel.cpp   \
core/src/lpsolver.cpp    \
core/src/stat.dispatch.cpp   \
core/src/matrix_decomp.cpp    \
core/src/trace.cpp    \
core/src/stat.cpp    \
core/src/cuda_stream.cpp   \
core/src/hal_internal.cpp    \
core/src/convert.avx2.cpp    \
core/src/convert.fp16.cpp   \
core/src/opengl.cpp    \
core/src/stl.cpp    \
core/src/copy.cpp    \
core/src/parallel_pthreads.cpp   \
core/src/alloc.cpp     \
core/src/directx.cpp    \
core/src/arithm.cpp     \
core/src/lda.cpp    \
core/src/va_intel.cpp    \
core/src/split.cpp    \
core/src/convert.sse4_1.cpp   \
core/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp    \
core/src/tables.cpp    \
core/src/out.cpp    \
core/src/cuda_info.cpp   \
core/src/mathfuncs.cpp     \
core/src/system.cpp     \
core/src/merge.cpp    \
core/src/mathfuncs_core.dispatch.cpp   \
core/src/matrix.cpp   \
core/src/command_line_parser.cpp   \
core/src/conjugate_gradient.cpp    \
core/src/softfloat.cpp     \
core/src/cuda_gpu_mat.cpp     \
core/src/persistence.cpp    \
core/src/ovx.cpp    \
core/src/array.cpp    \
core/src/dxt.cpp     \
core/src/glob.cpp     \
core/src/pca.cpp     \
core/src/kmeans.cpp    \
core/src/types.cpp    \
core/src/matmul.cpp    \
core/src/ocl.cpp   \
core/src/opencl/runtime/opencl_clamdfft.cpp  \
core/src/opencl/runtime/opencl_clamdblas.cpp   \
core/src/opencl/runtime/opencl_core.cpp    \
core/src/matop.cpp   \
core/src/convert.cpp   \
core/src/algorithm.cpp    \
core/src/downhill_simplex.cpp   \
core/src/umatrix.cpp    \
core/src/datastructs.cpp    \
core/test/test_misc.cpp    \
core/test/test_umat.cpp   \
core/test/test_eigen.cpp   \
core/test/test_ippasync.cpp   \
core/test/test_countnonzero.cpp   \
core/test/test_utils.cpp    \
core/test/test_rotatedrect.cpp   \
core/test/test_operations.cpp    \
core/test/test_math.cpp    \
core/test/test_io.cpp\
core/test/test_ptr.cpp\
core/test/test_hal_core.cpp\
core/test/test_mat.cpp\
core/test/test_main.cpp\
core/test/test_dxt.cpp\
core/test/test_concatenation.cpp\
core/test/ocl/test_matrix_expr.cpp    \
core/test/ocl/test_gemm.cpp    \
core/test/ocl/test_dft.cpp   \
core/test/ocl/test_channels.cpp   \
core/test/ocl/test_image2d.cpp   \
core/test/ocl/test_matrix_operation.cpp   \
core/test/ocl/test_arithm.cpp   \
core/test/test_intrin.cpp   \
core/test/test_downhill_simplex.cpp   \
core/test/test_rand.cpp    \
core/test/test_conjugate_gradient.cpp   \
core/test/test_arithm.cpp    \
core/test/test_ds.cpp   \
core/test/test_lpsolver.cpp   \
core/CMakeFiles/3.9.1/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp   \
core/misc/java/src/cpp/core_manual.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are x86 specific intrinsics. I really doubt that the CUDA support is able to be built for Android. Probably just remove that file from `CORE_SOURCE`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it in your own way, I tried to delete some of the files that went wrong, or only compiled to the beginning of "pref_" file. I am not familiar with the role of these documents, so I do not know how to be good. . .

Comment: Thank you very much, this problem has been solved, the problem is caused by a file called 'cv_cpu_config.h', I used to use the x86 header file causes this problem.